# How i can get the types of the parameters of an method for a WMI class

Tags: vbscript, wmi

How i can get the parameters types of an method for a WMI class using vbscript

actually i'm using this script

```
strComputer = "."
strNameSpace = "root\cimv2"
Set objServices = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
Set objShare = objServices.Get("Win32_Share")

Set objInParam = objShare.Methods_("Create"). _
    inParameters.Properties_

For Each Property In objInParam 
    WScript.Echo Property.Name
    WScript.Echo Property.Type //here this code fails, how i can get the type name ?
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `objInParam` you get out is a [SWbemPropertySet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393805%28VS.85%29.aspx#properties) that contains [SWbemProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393804%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and as you can see in the docs, there is no `Type` property of that class. However, there is the [CIMType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393810%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property that you can use instead.

The only difficulty with this is that `CIMType` returns an `Integer`, but you can find all the possible values in the documentation for the [WbemCimTypeEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393974%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) enum.

So if you'd be happy with the integer you'd have to change your code to:

```
For Each Property In objInParam 
    WScript.Echo Property.Name
    WScript.Echo Property.CIMType 
Next
```

Or if you need a string name you'd have to do something like:

```
For Each Property In objInParam 
    WScript.Echo Property.Name
    WScript.Echo GetTypeName(Property.CIMType)
Next

Function GetTypeName(typeNumber)
   ' fill in with a lookup table to the WbemCimTypeEnum '
End Function
```